# When can I peek at facedown tiles?

Tags: apotheca

In Apotheca tiles are placed facedown with an arrow indicating which player placed them.

While the rules say you can peek at cards, it doesn't say when it is valid for you to do so, only that you seemingly can't peek at cards while laying down new ones.

When can a player peek at times they have placed? Only during their turn? Before/after any action, but not during?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to create a tag for `apotheca`, so I'm hoping someone with the rep can remove house rules from this and add that one instead.